# How to get full history of IFile Eclipse Team IFileHistoryProvider when file has been moved within multimodule project?

Tags: eclipse, version-control, egit, revision-history

I am trying to access the full repository history of an `IFile` object programatically from an Eclipse plugin.  When the file has never been renamed or moved, the following code snippet works:

```java
public long getFileHistoryTimestamp(IFile file, IProgressMonitor monitor, boolean lastModified) {
    IProject project = file.getProject();
    RepositoryProvider rProv = RepositoryProvider.getProvider(project);
    long createdMillis, lastModifiedMillis;
    if (rProv !=null) {
        IFileHistoryProvider fhp = rProv.getFileHistoryProvider();
        if (fhp != null) {
            IFileHistory fHist = fhp.getFileHistoryFor((IResource) file, 
                    IFileHistoryProvider.NONE, null);
            IFileRevision[] revs = fHist.getFileRevisions();
            Arrays.sort(revs, new Comparator<IFileRevision>(){
                   public int compare(IFileRevision o1, IFileRevision o2) {
                       return Long.compare(o1.getTimestamp(), o2.getTimestamp());
                   }
            });
            for (IFileRevision rev : revs) {
                if (rev.getTimestamp() >= 0) {
                    createdMillis = rev.getTimestamp();
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (revs.length > 0) {
                lastModifiedMillis = revs[revs.length - 1].getTimestamp();
            }
       }

       return lastModified ? lastModifiedMillis : createdMillis;
}
```

But, if the file has been moved (e.g. with a multi-module maven project to a new or different module/project), then the values returned above are *only* for the file in it's current location - i.e. it does not track any rename/moves.  The same file in the Eclipse Team History view *does* track the full version history.

How can I access this full history within the Eclipse Team API?

Comment: When I try renaming on my Eclipse which only has local history (no Git, SVN, ....) I don't get any tracking of rename / move in the history. So my guess is this isn't part of the core API. Maybe look at the particular history view code for egit to see what it does.

Comment: Thanks @greg-449 - it took some digging to get anywhere near the answer via the git history view.  I think it would be better to provide it as an option in the flags for the `IFileHistoryProvider#getFileHistoryFor()` method.  As it happens there is also an open feature request for this at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=528236

Comment: That request is 5 years old and has no progress, so don't expect that to ever happen.

Comment: Yes - I suspect I will have to make something bespoke based on the egit/jgit but will see if I trigger any sort of response